# gRPC slow bandwidth to remote server

Tags: go, networking, grpc

I have a gRPC service that transfers files from a local machine to a remote server, and I'm noticing some significant bandwidth issues. On average, it's downloading at about 1mb/s with one connection sharing several streams (usually about 8).

The server uses TLS to encryption, but that doesn't seem to be the bottleneck, as turning off TLS has negligible effect on the performance. I've also tried using `iperf3` to test the bandwidth directly between the client and the server, and it resulted in 10mb/s.

```
Connecting to host <host>, port <port>
[  7] local 10.0.0.112 port 59651 connected to <ip> port <port>
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  7]   0.00-1.00   sec  1.28 MBytes  10.7 Mbits/sec
[  7]   1.00-2.00   sec   894 KBytes  7.35 Mbits/sec
[  7]   2.00-3.00   sec   999 KBytes  8.17 Mbits/sec
[  7]   3.00-4.00   sec  1.19 MBytes  10.0 Mbits/sec
[  7]   4.00-5.00   sec   753 KBytes  6.17 Mbits/sec
[  7]   5.00-6.00   sec  1.16 MBytes  9.67 Mbits/sec
[  7]   6.00-7.00   sec  1.00 MBytes  8.44 Mbits/sec
[  7]   7.00-8.00   sec  1.26 MBytes  10.5 Mbits/sec
[  7]   8.00-9.00   sec  1.22 MBytes  10.2 Mbits/sec
[  7]   9.00-10.00  sec  1.15 MBytes  9.66 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  7]   0.00-10.00  sec  10.8 MBytes  9.09 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  7]   0.00-10.00  sec  10.7 MBytes  8.95 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

The upload bandwidth from the client is about 10mb/s, and the download of the server is about 50mb/s (via `speedtest-cli`)

`traceroute` doesn't show anything interesting either...

```
traceroute to mikemeredith.ddns.net (108.52.111.249), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  2.195 ms  5.388 ms  1.385 ms
 2  <ip>  (<ip>)  8.256 ms  145.115 ms  19.025 ms
 3  <ip2> (<ip2>)  9.951 ms  9.471 ms  141.929 ms
 4  <ip3> (<ip3>)  18.389 ms  9.684 ms  12.248 ms
 5  <ip4> (<ip4>)  143.880 ms  25.077 ms  10.606 ms
 6  ae-13-ar01.capitolhghts.md.bad.comcast.net (68.87.168.61)  142.567 ms  137.153 ms  20.790 ms
 7  be-33657-cr02.ashburn.va.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.90.57)  14.326 ms  144.076 ms  22.957 ms
 8  be-1102-cs01.ashburn.va.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.32.169)  13.881 ms  144.756 ms  23.981 ms
 9  be-2107-pe07.ashburn.va.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.32.186)  20.203 ms  94.433 ms  23.034 ms
10  n-a.gw12.iad8.alter.net (152.179.50.205)  20.254 ms  278.023 ms  31.660 ms
11  * * *
12  <ip12> (<ip13>)  66.277 ms  39.229 ms  34.543 ms
13  <ip13> (<ip14>)  48.849 ms  49.300 ms  49.546 ms
```

Here's the actual code

Client Connection:

```golang
creds, err := credentials.NewClientTLSFromFile(cerLoc, "")
if err != nil {
    fmt..Printf("failed to get tls from file: %v\n", err)
    panic(err)
}
conn, err = grpc.Dial(host+port, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))
```

Client Stream:

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
defer cancel()
client := proto.Client(conn)
stream, err := client.BackupFiles(ctx, grpc.UseCompressor(gzip.Name))
// Send on stream, max size of message is 2mb
```

Server Listening:

```golang
// Start serving on port
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error listening on port %v: %v\n", port, err)
    panic(err)
}

var s *grpc.Server
creds, err := credentials.NewServerTLSFromFile(
    certLoc,
    keyLoc,
)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error getting tls certs: %v\n", err)
    panic(err)
}
s = grpc.NewServer(grpc.Creds(creds))
proto.RegisterBackupServer(s, &server{})
err = s.Serve(l)


// Actual stream handling

// Get a pooled SharedBuffer for assembling the file
b := getBuffer()
defer putBuffer(b)
c := make(chan int, []50)
u, _ := user.Current()

uid := uuid.New()
fout, err := os.Create(filePath + uid.String())
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error creating staging file: ", err)
    panic(err)
}
var wg sync.WaitGroup

go assemble(b, fout, c, &wg)
for {
    in, err := stream.Recv()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("encountered an error receiving on stream: ", err)
        return err
    }


    bytesWritten = b.LockWrite(in.Payload) // This buffer is shared between the stream and the go routine

    c <- bytesWritten
}


close(c)
wg.Wait()

_ = fout.Close()

// This is a pre-declared workerpool that basically moves files around 
wp.Submit(func() {
    finalizeFile(fout.Name(), name, perms, "", checkSum, userID)
})

return stream.SendAndClose(&proto.Resp{
    Status:   true,
})

func assemble(b *buffer.SharedBuffer, fout *os.File, in chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()

    buf := make([]byte, buffer.BUFFSIZE*2)

    for i := range in {
        if fout != nil {
            b.Lock()
            _, err := b.Read(buf[:i])
            b.Unlock()
            if err == io.EOF {
                continue
            }
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            n, err := fout.Write(buf[:i])
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            if n != i {
                fmt.Printf("failed to write all bytes to file: %v != %v", n, i)
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Seems like I might be missing something with the inner workings of gRPC?

Comment: Why have you omitted the necessary parts of the code base?

Comment: Probably the bottleneck is the code you omitted. That is, where you actually read the grpc messages and write their payload to file. Moreover, if you suspect performance issues in your Go programs, you can always trace their execution and see if you find the bottleneck.
https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2017/go-execution-tracer/

Comment: @diyoda_ because its ~~proprietary~~, there's nothing special with the connection so i can share that. I'll update the code with code that somewhat similar to the actual code.

Comment: @GiulioMicheloni i'll be updating the code shortly with some more details

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you are reading the input stream within one goroutine and dispatch the bytes to a second goroutine. Why don't you let the second goroutine handle the stream entirely? In this way the first goroutine is free to process the following streams, if any.

Typically the pattern is to have one goroutine that listens for incoming requests and spawns new goroutines for handling them. It is crutial that the main goroutine does not call any blocking API, besides the one to listen for requests.

For example:

```
for {
    newStream := ListenForStreams() //Block until next stream
    go consumeStream(newStream)
}
```

Comment: Well yes and no. the gRPC server automatically multithreads streams on the same connection, so each stream gets its own go routine. Then, in order to not read the entire file into memory at once, the second go routine reads out of the buffer into a file.

Comment: IMHO, two goroutines for each stram is not necessary. You could perform the chunking of input stream directly in the same goroutine that also writes the chunks to output file. Having more goroutines than needed may lead to high contention and then bad concurrency. Moreover, what is the size of buffer and channel? Make sure that they are not too small. I would reccomend to trace your executable to see what is going on.

Comment: Well the first go routine is out of my control--every stream that the server gets, gRPC automatically spins up a go routine to handle it (or rather, i think it gets it out of a pool). The reason i choose this route was to just get as much in to the buffer as possible w/o waiting to write to the file. The buffer is a `bytes.Buffer`, so resizable, and the channel is 50.

Comment: It makes sense. The prototype looks ok to me then. I can only suggest to use the tracer to spot the critical path and possibly improve it.